# Importing Data with DataGrab from Grid

Tags: import, datagrab

I have EE 2.7.3 with a grid-field.
In this grid I have 3 fields. Two of them are date-fields, one is a text-field.

By the import i can only see the main customfield for this grid. I take this field for all the options i can fill in.

When I run the import it will not import the dates from the two date-fields.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running DataGrab 1.8?

Comment: Yes, I do. Wrote also in his Forum, but get no answer. That's why I try it here.